Why is my MNIST-trained model misclassifying a custom image?
I have trained a neural network model using the MNIST dataset to recognize handwritten digits. The model achieves a 97% accuracy on the MNIST test set, but it fails to correctly predict digits from a custom image file. For example, the image below contains the digit 8, but the model's prediction is always incorrect.
What am I doing wrong in the preprocessing step, and how can I correctly prepare my custom images to match the MNIST data format?
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.api.datasets import mnist
from keras.api.models import Sequential
from keras.api.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.api.utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image


# Load the MNIST dataset
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

# Converts mnist data set from uint8 to float32, because most deep learning frameworks expect input data to be in floating-point format.
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

# Adds a new channel dimension resulting in a shape of (num_samples, 28, 28, 1)
train_images = np.expand_dims(train_images, axis=-1)
test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images, axis=-1)

# One-hot encode the labels
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

# Build the model
model = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
print("Training the model...")
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

# Evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

# Load an image for prediction
image_path = 'digit.png'  # Replace with your image path
print(f"Loading and predicting for {image_path}...")

try:
    # Read the image in grayscale
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    if image is None:
        raise IOError(f"Error loading image at {image_path}")

    # Resize the image to 28x28
    image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))

    # Invert the colors (if needed)
    image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)

    # Normalize the image
    image_normalized = image.astype('float32') / 255

    # Convert to a format that can be saved as PNG (values 0 to 255)
    image_for_saving = (image_normalized * 255).astype(np.uint8)

    # Define the path for saving the image
    preprocessed_image_path = "preprocessed_digit.png"
    
    # Ensure the directory exists (current directory)
    output_directory = os.path.dirname(preprocessed_image_path)
    if not os.path.exists(output_directory) and output_directory != '':
        os.makedirs(output_directory)
    
    # Save the image using PIL
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(image_for_saving)
    pil_image.save(preprocessed_image_path)
    print(f"Saved preprocessed image to {preprocessed_image_path}")

    # Predict the digit using your model (assuming model is already loaded)
    # Reshape image to model input format if necessary
    image_input = np.expand_dims(image_normalized, axis=0)
    image_input = np.expand_dims(image_input, axis=-1)
    prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(image_input))
    print("Predicted Digit:", prediction)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error processing the image: {e}")


If your custom image is on a non-white back ground or it is not square shaped (rectangle shaped images being resized to square would distort them) it might not recognize it since MNIST data set is perfectly square and on white back ground. Your model is not trained to handle those cases.

So if my custom image is on a non white background. When I am training my model why would I feed it trained images from MNIST? Instead of using MNIST data set. I have my own data set I want to use and for it to train on.
